# Filter movies from the movie database api. SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, themoviedb-api

I want to filter moves based on genre, release year, etc. And ultimately able to use multiple filters. How can I link my filter parameters with that of the API?
Here is how my filterView looks like; let me take genre as an example.

```
let allGenres: [Filter] = [Filter(name: "Action"), Filter(name: "Comedy"), Filter(name: "Drama"), Filter(name: "Fantasy"), Filter(name: "Horror"), Filter(name: "Romance"), Filter(name: "Thriller"), Filter(name: "Sciencee Fiction"), Filter(name: "Mystery")]

struct FilterView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var genres: String?

    @State var selectedGenre: Set<Filter> = []

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                   VStack {
                        MultiSelector(
                            label: Text("Genre"),
                            options: allGenres,
                            optionToString: { $0.name },
                            selected: $selectedGenre
                        )
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    saveSelectedValues(genres: selectedGenre)
                    
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Done")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width:300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.accentColor)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Filter")
        }
    }
}

func saveSelectedValues(genres: Set<Filter>) {
    // Convert the selected options to an array of their names
    let selectedGenres = genres.map { $0.name }
    
    // Save the selected values to UserDefaults, database, or any other storage mechanism
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedGenres, forKey: "selectedGenre")
}
```

And at the same time how do I perserve the selected filters when the filterView get's called again.

This is the code for the filter button

```
struct RandomiserView: View {

    @Binding var genres: String?

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 10)
                Button("Filters") {
                    isShowingFilters.toggle()
                }
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width:300, height: 50)
                .background(Color.accentColor)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingFilters) {
                    FilterView(genres: $genres
                }

                Spacer()
```

If anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `...what I'm doing wrong ...`, you don't call the API, that is why you can't answer `How can I link my filter parameters with that of the API?`.